# Export dreamweaver cs5 site setups to another dreamweaver instalation

Tags: dreamweaver

I have a bunch of sites setup in dreamweaver cs5, and I need to install them to fresh dreamweaver install. I mainly want to export the info in "site setup", as I have the files in an external HD. Does anyone know of an easy way to export the "site setup" info of all the sites at once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Site->Manage Sites
2. Select all items in the list
3. Click Export
4. Choose whether to back up all data, or exclude a few things
5. Select folder

All sites will be exported to the chosen folder as separate .ste files.

Comment: Ooo thanks, I hadn't noticed that before - this will save tons of time!